# How to creating mock objects with Jasmine using createSpy()

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, jasmine

I’m trying to set up a mock unit test with jasmine by using createSpy(). I’ve getting

> TypeError: `undefined` is not a function (evaluating `jasmine.createSpy().andCallFake(function(msg) { return [] })`) (line 13).

**CODE:**

```
  $scope.workInit = function() {
    $scope.work_loading = true;
    $scope.public_work_loading = true;

    var projects = SomeService.getGroups();
    var publicProjects = SomeService.getPublicGroupings('G');
    …
     ...
  }
```

**TEST:**

```
 this.SomeService = {
    getGroups: jasmine.createSpy().andCallFake(function(msg) { return [] }),
    getPublicGroupings: jasmine.createSpy().andCallFake(function(msg) { return [] }),
}

  it('should expect work_loading and public_loading to be false', function () {
    this.scope.workInit();
    expect($scope.work_loading).toEqual(false);
    expect($scope.public_work_loading).toEqual(false);
  });
```

Comment: `this.scope.workInit();` or **`this.scope.workgInit();`** ?

Comment: its this.scope.workInit();  sorry it was a typo. i'll update that, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The way you have set up the mock unit test case is correct, the same works for me in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aditiraveesh/02kr1oem/1/).

Check the scope in which you've included this part of the code:

```
this.SomeService = {
    getGroups: jasmine.createSpy().andCallFake(function(msg) { return [] }),
    getPublicGroupings: jasmine.createSpy().andCallFake(function(msg) { return [] }),
```